# Visual Studio cannot link to Allegro?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, allegro5

I'm following the basic Allegro 5 tutorial to try to make my first basic Allegro project, but despite following the instructions to the letter I cannot successfully link to the libraries.

Here were the instructions:

---

Under Configuration Properties->C/C++->General, enter c:\allegro\include in Additional Include Directories.

Under Configuration Properties->Linker->General, enter c:\allegro\lib in Additional Library Directories.

Under Configuration Properties->Linker->Input, append allegro-5.0.5-monolith-md-debug.lib to Additional Dependencies.

Under Configuration Properties->Debugging, enter PATH=c:\allegro\bin;%PATH% in Environment.

Click Apply.

Visual C++ can now link your project with the Allegro 5 library.

You should now select the "Release" configuration (upper left corner) and repeat the steps with one minor change: use the non-debug library allegro-5.0.5-monolith-md.lib.

---

But then it gives me the following error nevertheless:

LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'allegro-5.0.5-monolith-md-debug.lib'

Ideas?

Comment: Wow, answered my own question. You have to update the Linker Input file path thing. The current version is 5.0.6 -- just change that and it works.

Comment: could you specify "the Linker Input file path thing" a little more?

Comment: I'm out and about at present, using a *Mac*, so I can't open up Visual Studio and check until later. But try going back through the settings you changed to include Allegro in the first place, if you did, which you ought to have, and looking for the version number which you copied out of the instructions which is NOT the version number of the version you actually downloaded. If your problem correlates to mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't realize this was getting a bunch of views; I would have put up the answer eons ago. Hopefully people have been seeing my comment containing the answer--

> Wow, answered my own question. You have to update the Linker Input file path thing. The current version is 5.0.6 -- just change that and it works.

Basically their installation instructions aren't updated to reflect the current version. Make sure you change things accordingly when changing project linker settings to include Allegro.